# Eukaryotic DNA polymerase in Leading and Lagging Strand

Tags: molecular-biology, taxonomy, dna-replication

**Different books say a different specifications on which eukaryotic DNA polymerase work in leading strand and which DNA polymerase work in lagging strand.**

TL,DR: Which one is reality? and if there are multiple possibility, then which one is applicable for which organism (such as human mammal, yeast fungus, *Arabidopsis* plant etc.)?

**Information greatly varying Such as,**

According to book The Cell by G.M. Cooper ([NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK9940/)), in mammalian eukaryotic system, *DNA polymerase δ works in both leading and lagging strand.*

> [image: Screenshot from Cooper]

According to book Molecular biology by R. F. Weaver, ed-5; *DNA pol- δ works in lagging strand and pol ε works in lagging strand* and DNA pol ε work in leading strand.

> [image: Screenshot from Weaver]

Fundamentals of molecular biology, Lizabeth Allison ([Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Fundamental-Molecular-Biology-Allison/d7478c93f50f437d0fe852c530bd245d2e3bbe42/figure/84)) says another thing, it says pol ε works on lagging strand.

> [image: Allison table]

The paper by Stillman B. , DNA polymerases at the replication fork in eukaryotes. ([NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18471969)) ([NCBI-PMC](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2919282/)) ([FIGURE](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2919282/figure/F1/)) says in SV40 viral model the δ polymerase works in both strand but in cell chromosome, δ works on lagging and &epsilon works in leading strand.

> [image: Stillman B]

Now which one is true? if all are true then does they applicable on different organism?

Comment: You have the seeds of the answer in the sources you quote. Some are books — which will be up-to-date perhaps a year before publication — and one is a paper. Check the publication dates, and check the paper to see if more recent related works are flagged. In fact, a review from 2018 is cited. I know nothing about the topic, but it is evident from the summaries that views have changed over the past 20 years. Read the recent review to find out the evidence for the (almost) current view, and perhaps why previous ideas have been superseded. NCBI Bookshelf is very useful, but only has old editions.